# regex for identifying portion of a URL in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this URL http://random.com/personal/randonNumber/default.aspx  .How can I make sure the url has personal/*/default.aspx in it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(location.href.search(/\/personal\/[^\/]+\/default.aspx/)>-1) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var str = "http://random.com/personal/randonNumber/default.aspx";
var pattern = /personal\/.*\/default.aspx/g;
if (str.search(pattern) != -1) {
    console.log("Matched");
}
else {
    console.log("No match");
}
```